# Using scrapy to simulate user login

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning how to use Scrapy to login to html forms. This is an example of code for a login spider with a little alteration from Scrapy's tutorial:

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

```
def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'wrongusername', 'password': 'wrongpassword'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "Invalid" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return
    else:
        print "Not forwarding to failed login page"

    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

I purposely put incorrect login information so that it would search for the string "invalid". However, the console does not print the error message from the log. "username" and "password" are the correct "name"s for the input fields in the form so that should not be a problem. Also, "Invalid" does appear as a string when incorrect login information is entered, so that should not be the problem. Also, it seems when incorrect login information is entered, the error message appears but it has the same url as the original login page. Would this be an issue if the site does not forward me to another page? It seems scrapy is searching the original login page (when no information is entered) and that is why it cannot find "Invalid".

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: have you tried removing `[]` from your `parse() ... return `?

Comment: @Anzel I removed [] from parse() but it still does not work.

Comment: can you show the web url exactly? it could be that there are more than 1 x form, or another reason. We may then have a look and help you

Answer (score -1):

Try to find "authentication failed" instead of "Invalid" in response.body, as stated in the [Scrapy manual](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin).